# Invoking (looping through) a list of MySQL rows in PHP gives unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, repeat

Two snippets of PHP code:

The first one works fine, giving values from different rows sequentially.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rst)) {
...
$link1 = $row['audio1'];
    if ($link1) {
    $link1 = $link1;
    }
...
}
```

The second one outputs the value from the first row and applies it to every subsequent row.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rst)) {
...
if ($row['audio1']) {
    $link1 = $row['audio1'];
    }
...
}
```

I.e. where the first code sample generates

```
Audio1.mp3
Audio2.mp3
Audio3.mp3
```

the second one would generate

```
Audio1.mp3
Audio1.mp3
Audio1.mp3
```

The question is why those two similar implementations differ in output.

Another test case with ...s removed (clean loop code) yields a different picture: the first example only outputs one line (the first one), the second example's output is the same which is repeating lines.

MySQL table that is being used has the following structure:
One table,
INT (id), CHAR, SMALLINT, TINYTEXT, TEXT, TEXT, TINYTEXT (audio1). All of the rows are fully populated except for the last one (audio1) which is mostly empty and has non-NULL values somewhere in the middle (if we sort by id field).
Replacing the 'audio1' with another column name yields correct results (for that field) in both cases.

Another addition is that I do indeed place a SELECT statement initially in mysql_query that filters out rows. Depending on the number of rows being returned the picture for the second example may be slightly different, like 3 non-repeating values followed by a repetition of the third value until the end.

Comment: The portions you post are indeed equivalent. So, the error must hide in the `...` somewhere...

Comment: there shouldn't be any difference. the first one is somewhat pointless: `if (value is non-falsey) { value = value }`.

Comment: `if ($link1) {$link1 = $link1;}` ...what?

Comment: Yep, sorry it looks weird, actually it's not $link=$link, that line is wrapping the contents of the cell into a tag, i.e. <audio controls src="$link1"></audio> basically but I removed that code for brevity.

Comment: Also the if clause is present to avoid unnecessary <audio> tags in case the cell value is empty.

Comment: I removed all the ...s and left just the bare code shown here and now I only get one row even with the code that used to work. The structure of the table is as follows: INT (id), CHAR, SMALLINT, TINYTEXT, TEXT, TEXT, TINYTEXT (Audio). All of them are fully populated without empty spaces and only the last one (Audio) is populated sparsely, the first time it is not empty is somewhere in the middle if we sort by IDs.

Comment: Edit your post and put the full block of code.  What you posted doesn't indicate the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Long story short - it was really obvious: between loop cycles $link1 variable didn't change in case `if` wasn't `true`. What I needed to do was to put `$link1 = "";` or `unset ($link);` right after `while` and in that case if I ever encountered an empty value for `$row['audio1']` it would stay truly empty instead of reusing the old value for every new row.